# How can I iterate over a list of integers, and reference the largest key in my dictionary (all integers) so that it is smaller than current value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with positive integers as `keys`, the `values` don't matter for my question.

Separately, I am iterating through a `list of integers`, and I want to reference the largest key in my dictionary, that is smaller than the current integer that I am iterating over in my list (if it exists!).

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def Loep(obstacles):
    my_dict = defaultdict(int)
    output = []

    for i in range(len(obstacles)):

        if max(j for j in my_dict.keys() if j<= obstacles[i]):
            temp = max(j for j in my_dict.keys() if j<= obstacles[i])
            my_dict[obstacles[i]] = temp + 1
            output.append(my_dict[obstacles[i]])
        else:
            my_dict[obstacles[i]] = 1
            output.append(my_dict[obstacles[i]])
            
print(Loep([3,1,5,6,4,2]))
```

I am getting an error for the `'if' statement` above- I believe it is because I have one too many arguments in `max()`, any ideas how to amend the code?

The error is: `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

I've tried separating it, but I can't quite do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def Loep(obstacles):
    my_dict = defaultdict(int)

    my_dict.update({
        1: 0,
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
        4: 0,
        5: 0,
        6: 0,
    })
    output = []

    for obstacle in obstacles:
        keys = [j for j in my_dict.keys() if j <= obstacle]
        if keys:
            # there is at least one qualifying key
            key = max(keys)
            my_dict[obstacle] = key + 1
            output.append(my_dict[obstacle])
        else:
            my_dict[obstacle] = 1
            output.append(my_dict[obstacle])

    return output

print(Loep([3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 2]))
```

In response to your comment about doing it in one line.. yes, you could condense it like so:

```
    for obstacle in obstacles:
        key = max([None]+[j for j in my_dict.keys() if j <= obstacle])
        if key is not None:
            # etc
```

.. and definitely there are other ways to do it.. using filter.. or other ways.. but end of the day you are trying to not just get the max, but to get the max lower than a specific value.  Unless you're working with a very large amount of data, or in need of extreme speed.. that this is the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks little_birdie, this is what I thought we had to do too. So there is not way of directly obtaining the maximum in one line? And instead we have to put it into a list, then take the max? Is this the only way?

Comment: I edited my answer to show a slightly shorter way.  But basically, unless you are going for extreme performance optimization, there is no one-liner I can think of that will be much (if at all) better...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Is it what you want?

```
from collections import defaultdict
def Loep(obstacles):
    my_dict = defaultdict(int)
    output = []
    for i in range(len(obstacles)):
        founds = [j for j in my_dict.keys() if j <= obstacles[i]]
        if founds:
            max_val = max(founds)
            my_dict[obstacles[i]] = max_val + 1
        else:
            my_dict[obstacles[i]] = 1
        output.append(my_dict[obstacles[i]])
    return output

print(Loep([3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 2]))
```

Comment: I still get the same error Trock.. even after changing it